# GD Quality Issue with Transparent PNGs

Tags: php, gd

I'm getting some very bad quality using GD to resize some PNGs. If I don't resize them, it seems fine, and if I use GD's negate filter, it seems fine as well, which is very weird. But nothing else seems to help.

This is happening with timthumb (latest) and aq_resize for wordpress.

Here is one image, processed with timthumb:

http://cdn.squidix.com/images/branding/name-white.png?h=150

The original of this image is white text over a transparent background. The white text has no border, it just blurs into transparency. It will only let me post one link here, take off the ?h=150 to see the original image (you won't see it in your browser, because it's completely white, download it to see it).

But after being processed with GD, it has grainy light gray artifacts in the background, and there's now a gray border around the white text. If you're using an LCD, look up at it from an angle and you'll see how bad it is.

Update: This doesn't happen with imagecopyresized, only imagecopyresampled.

PHPInfo - http://cdn.squidix.com/

Comment: That's to be expected. The background isn't a single color. It's a speckled mesh of at least two "close" shades of pink. e.g. it's not GD's fault. garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: See the new image I posted. Take off the ?h= and it will look fine, because it only routes to timthumb if there's a query string.

Comment: it STILL has a speckled background. just in two+ shades of grey now.

Comment: I know, GD is adding that speckled background. It's not on the original. http://cdn.squidix.com/images/branding/name-white.png

Comment: See the border of this - http://cdn.squidix.com/images/branding/name-white.png?h=150 as opposed to the link above. The original image looks nothing like that. GD is turning the small transparency on the border of the text into a gray color.

Comment: Interesting... What all are you going in GD, exactly?

Comment: You mean doing? Just resizing with timthumb. No filters, nothing fancy.

Comment: Also, when I use GD's negate filter, the problem goes away. No more speckled background. See here - http://cdn.squidix.com/images/branding/name-white.png?f=1&h=150